# Internet Explorer Compatibility

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8

I want to run an application in IE 8 and other on IE 11 on same system. Is it possible to run 'internet explorer 8' together with 'internet explorer 11' using virtual machine or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, running multiple simultaneous versions of IE on the same system is no longer supported.  Yes, you can run multiple version using a VM, but that's really not running them on the "same system".

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're testing browser compatibility or something similiar, I'd suggest using the F12 developer tools and utilizing the browswer emulation tools.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score -1):

For this @Ritesh you will need to get separate packages for both Internet explorer software packages i.e. 7 and 11 and extract them using Archive processors, or use **Universal Extractor** easily available on net...

And place them in your local drives not in Operating OS's drive, that might help you.